# Assign more than one value to an element in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, element

### Background Info

I am designing a program in `C++` to generate a weekly rota for my work.
It begins by specifying certain criteria, such as how many hours each person is required to work as well as what types of shifts they should work i.e. only day shifts, only at the weekend, etc.
The way I was thinking of designing the part of the code that randomly generates the rota was to initialize a `7 x 18 array` (7 days in the week and 18 hours of working hours to cover a day). The program would then start with a for loop to determine what day and then a nested for loop to determine what hour of the day we are focussing on (sorry I know the terminology usage here is a bit sketchy). Each hour of each day it would generate a random number and assign it to the element. (Note: each person at the start of the program is assigned an integer to represent them.)

### My question

I want to assign elements in the array more than one value (I require more than one person to work at any given time.) So I was wondering if this is even possible and if so, how would I go about doing it. 
The code that I have so far is inserted below. 
(Note: I do realise that this is at its very beginning stages. I first want to see if my general idea works before spending a lot of time writing it up.)
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()

{  ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open("array.dat");

   srand(time(NULL));

   int NoOfDaysInWeek=7;
   int NoOfHoursinDay=18;

   int array[NoOfDaysInWeek][NoOfHoursinDay];

   James=1;
   Mark=2;
   Will=3;
   Jamie=4;
   Lisa=5;
   Sandra=6;
   Chris=7;
   Julia=8;
   Jane=9;
   Anne=10;
   Alexandra=11;
   Jenny=12;

   for (int i=0; i<NoOfDaysInWeek; i++) { // loop for day of week
      for (int j=2; j<12; j++) {         // loop for hours 2 to 12 (already           
         array[i][j]=5;
      }
      for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
         array[i][j]=(rand() % 4)+1;  // only want mark, james, will or jamie to get these shifts.
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of an array of `int`, maybe you should consider an array of `std::set`.

Comment: Just make an array of arrays of array, so that you have one row per day, one column per hour, and each cell is an array of jobs for the people.

Comment: Well, if you use `std::set`, then you should also probably consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of a plain array.

Comment: Instead of `int array[NoOfDaysInWeek][NoOfHoursinDay];`, use `std::set<int> worAssignments[NoOfDaysInWeek][NoOfHoursinDay];`

Comment: `James=1;` what is James??

Comment: You seem to be using C++ to solve a specific problem that is agnostic to the programming language. Given your level of experience, you might want to consider doing this in another, more forgiving (and simpler!) language such as Python.

Comment: Tbh I would prefer to stick with what I know ie `int array` then using `std::set` if possible

Comment: James is a person. Later I want the program to print the name and not the value onto an excel spreadsheet. But that is for another time

Comment: Giulio I was thinking that too, I just wasn't sure how to visualise it. Ie if I wanted 3 people working at one particular hour would I then want to create a 4 dimensional array, where the first dimension states the day, the second states person 1 working that day, 3rd dimension states person 2 working that day, etc?